# Yii 1 Select2 Getting Selected Value From Update Form

Tags: php, yii1.x

The following works to retrieve data and post to database, its just when i goto the update form it doesn't retrieve the selected record.

Anyone know how to get the selected value set?

See the way I am doing it is because I have 30k of records its pulling and select2 using this ajax fetch is the only way to do it without lagging.

Your help is appreciated

`````
        echo CHtml::hiddenField('pole_id', '', array('class' => 'span5'));
        $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
            'id'=>'myselect',
            'selector' => '#pole_id',
            'model'=>$model,
            'attribute'=>'pole_id', 
            'options'  => array(
                'allowClear'=>true,
                'placeholder'=>'Select a Pole',
                'minimumInputLength' => 3, 

                   'ajax' => array(
                    'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('jpapoles/poles'),
                     'type'=>'GET',
                    'dataType' => 'json',
                    'quietMillis'=> 100,
                    'data' => 'js: function(text,page) {
                    return {
                                q: text, 
                                page_limit: 10,
                                page: page,
                            };

                        }',

                    'results'=>'js:function(data,page) { var more = (page * 10) < data.total; return {results: data, more:more }; 

                    }

                    ',
                      ),

                   ),

        ));


        ?>````


    public function actionPoles()
    {
          $data =Poles::model()->findAll('pole_number like :Nome',array(':Nome'=>"%".$_GET['q']."%")); 

                   $results = array();

         foreach ($data as $list){

           $results[] = array(

                        'id'=>$list->id,

                        'text'=>  $list->pole_number,

           ); 

       }


    echo CJSON::encode($results);




    }
`````

Comment: on change event you get the selected option but view not work or all not work view and not work change and you not received the selected option... I had the same problem but i not use yi and i need set a name space to the on change event in javascript.

Comment: I have tried the following but still no success:  ``` ' initSelection'=>"js:function(element,callback) {
                      var id=".$model->pole_id ."; 
                         var text='".Poles::model()->findByPk($model->pole_id)->pole_number."'; 
                     data = {
                        'id': id,
                        'text': text
                      }
                }",
             ), ```

Answer (score 0):

```
// the IDs of the preselected models in string-form like '125, 56' 
// these are stored in $_POST after one submits the form and returns to it due to errors.
// we don't want to lose the values that were selected before the initial submission, 
// thus the need for an initSelection-implementation...

$preselected_ids = $_POST['ExistingParents'];

echo CHtml::textField("ExistingParents", $preselected_ids, array('style' => 'width:50%'));

$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array('selector' => "#ExistingParents", 'options' => array(

                    'allowClear'         => true,
                    'minimumInputLength' => 2,
                    'multiple'           => true,
                    'initSelection' => 'js:function (element, callback) {
        
            var selected_data = []; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "'.Yii::app()->createUrl('child/task/getParentsByIds').'",
                data: "ids='.$preselected_ids.'",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                    for (var key in result) {

                        if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                            selected_data.push({
                                id: result[key].id,
                                text: result[key].text
                            });
                            callback(selected_data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }',
        'ajax' => array(
            'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('child/task/getParents'),
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => 'js:function(term,page) { 
                return {
                    q: term, 
                    page_limit: 3, 
                    page: page
                }; 
            }',
            'results' => 'js:function(data,page) { 
                return {
                    results: data
                }; 
            }',
        ),


), 
));
```